# How to Calculate the Impedance of the Capacitor T network?

Tags: capacitor, impedance, biopotential

[image]

I guess Capacitor T network used in the schematics is for Impedance matching, if yes how to calculate the impedance of the same circuit?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It's unlikley it's due to impedance matching since the output of the sensor is buffered according to the datasheet. Put the values into your simulator, sweep the frequency and report your findings.

Comment: The sensor and R2 are a signal source which should not be considered as a rigid voltage output, but a current source with R2 in parallel. The capacitors and the opamp circuit should be (needs simulating to know)  a hefty bandpass amplifier which hopefully rejects ambient light changes as well as the normal 100Hz flicker of fluorescent lights, but amplifies the wanted pulse. Impedance matching is not a proper explanation. All caps are part of the bandpass circuit. As suggested: Simulate the circuit. Assume tiny AC current output from pin 4 of U1 and get the frequency response.

Comment: C1 and C2 *might* be some AC divider, and the opamp with the rest (except C3) *might* look like some phase shifter, but after a quick simulation the output looks awfully strange. What's more, you say you need this for bio-signals, but the APDS-9008 is an "ambient photo sensor" for "the measurement of ambient light". I am quite confused.

Comment: It's a circuit for a Pulse sensor which captures the voltages caused by the blood flow in our body. Refer: [link](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/PulseSensorAmpd%20-%20Schematic.pdf) @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: I will try to simulate the circuit as you suggested and let you know the results. @winny

Comment: @SivamNatesan Ok, so how does it work?

Comment: Its working fine, I am getting the Pulse signal out of it, but I want to know the working of the circuit, so that I can play around with it afterwards @aconcernedcitizen

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid to say that the circuit is a bit useless. At first glance it appears to be a 2nd order high pass sallen-key op-amp filter but, on closer inspection of components around the Vin- pin of the rather-boxy-looking op-amp, it appears the circuit has been drawn incorrectly and quite possibly made incorrectly. R5 should provide feedback from the op-amp output to the junction of C2 and C3 but unfortunately it's not connected to the output but to Vin- rendering it ineffectual.

What you appear to have is somebody's interpretation of what they should really have and, I expect that R6 has been pushed ever higher in value to obtain some partially useful filtering that the designer believes is correct.

Where did this circuit come from?

Comment: It's a circuit for a Pulse sensor which captures the voltages caused by the blood flow in our body. Refer: [link](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/PulseSensorAmpd%20-%20Schematic.pdf) @Andy

Comment: Since I am capturing and processing the bio-signals impedance should be matched because of its low frequency, so I guess that one is for impedance matching, not related to Op-Amp feedback.

Comment: @SivamNatesan sometimes, through just having reached a certain age in life and having seen almost all conceivable op-amp circuits, you get to know when a circuit is wrong and what it was intended to be. This, I feel, is one of those occasions.

Comment: Your 2nd comment is as flawed as the circuit you have posted. If you don't want to listen to me then that's OK but please don't try BS to convince me the light sensor requires impedance matching because you are capturing bio signals.

Comment: Since, I am new to this, I guessed that bio-signals requires impedance matching. Sorry if it offends you.